# WPF animate window height change, for height set to auto

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I created simple WPF application with this structure:

```
<Window ... MinWidth="300" MinHeight="200" Width="300" 
        Height="Auto" SizeToContent="Height">
  <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Info about loading"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

My application height depend on content height (in my example it depends on TextBlock size) and this working fine. But if I change Text content too massive, **height of my window change from old to new in one sharp jump**.
It is a possibility to animate this jump from one height to another and still use `Height="Auto"` for window? Animate Height manually is easy for fixed Height if I know what is end Height value. But what to do if I have Height set to auto and content Height is changed not continuous, but in one step from low to high?

Comment: One easy way to do this, slap a [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195722.aspx) on it.

Comment: Sorry, not so easy for me :) can you provide a example for my window?